# General Big-Data principles for finding pairs of similar objects - "fuzzy inner join"

Tags: database, join, bigdata

Firstly, sorry for the vague title and if this question has been asked before, but I was not entirely sure how to phrase it.

I am looking for general design principles for finding pairs of 'similar' objects from two different data sources.
Lets for simplicity say that we have two databases, A and B, both containing large volumes of objects, each with time-stamp and geo-location, along with some other data that we don't care about here.

Now I want to perform a search along these lines:
Within as certain time-frame and location dictated as search tiem, find pairs of objects from A and B respectively, ordered by some similarity score. Here for example some scalar 'time/space distance' function, distance(a,b), that calculates the distance in time and space between the objects.

I am expecting to get a (potentially ginormous) set of results where the first result is a pair of data points which has the minimum 'distance'.

I realize that the full search space is cardinality(A) x cardinality(B).

Are there any general guidelines on how to do this in a reasonable efficient way? I assume that I would need to replicate the two databases into a common repository like Hadoop? But then what? I am not sure how to perform such a query in Hadoop either.

What is this this type of query called?
To me, this is some kind of "fuzzy inner join" that I struggle wrapping my head around how to construct, let along efficiently at scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL joins don't have to be based on equality. You can use ">", "<", "BETWEEN".
You can even do something like this:

```
select a.val aval, b.val bval, a.val - b.val diff
from A join B on abs(a.val - b.val) < 100
```

Comment: But is a join like this scalable and practically feasible when reaching hundreds of millions of records? I have the suspicion that it might not be.

Comment: Join like that is not scalable on traditional RDBMS but on MPP platform it may be, depending on the expected cardinality. I don't know the specifics of your problem but as a general approach I would suggest:
1. Eliminate outliers that are of no use. 
2. Figure out the expected cardinality of the "fuzzy" join and find out how much horsepower you have. Some platforms may be able to handle sets as large as 100B records or more. 
3. Based on that see if you can split one of the two tables into partitions to process each separately.

Comment: 4. OronNavon suggested "bucketing" - which is a good approach, except I see how it can be problematic if you are comparing everything to everything. See to what extent you can take this approach without compromising your objectives.

If you find a "magic" technique - please share.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to divide your objects into buckets in advance, without comparing them (or at least making a linear, rather than square, number of comparisons).  That way, at query time, you will only be comparing a small number of items.

There is no "one-size-fits-all" way to bucket your items. In your case the bucketing can be based on time, geolocation, or both.  Time-based bucketing is very natural, and can also scales elastically (increase or decrease the bucket size).  Geo-clustering buckets can be based on distance from a particular point in space (if the space is abstract), or on some finite division of the space (for example, if you divide the entire Earth's world map into tiles, which can also scale nicely if done right).

A good question to ask is "if my data starts growing rapidly, can I handle it by just adding servers?" If not, you might need to rethink the design.